# Joomla 3.4.8 Require Password Reset Not Working

Tags: joomla, change-password

I am having trouble finding a solution. I am running a site that has about 50 users that are manually entered. I am requiring the users on the first login to create their own password. This fails to work and just refreshes the user-profile/profile?layout=edit page upon hitting the Submit button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

for solving problem you can add a record to a table users,that have a parameter like **fresh="true"**,when users go to website and change password.the fresh parameter is got **fresh="false"** for ever. and you can edit component users for do your idea...............

my offer you can use the source that users can sign up only with logging to their email like **gmail,email**